# how to save a list of case classes in scala

Tags: java, scala, save

I have a case class named Rdv:

```
case class Rdv(
  id: Option[Int],
  nom: String,
  prénom: String,
  sexe: Int,
  telPortable: String,
  telBureau: String,
  telPrivé: String,
  siteRDV: String,
  typeRDV: String,
  libelléRDV: String,
  numRDV: String,
  étape: String,
  dateRDV: Long,
  heureRDVString: String,
  statut: String,
  orderId: String)
```

and I would like to save a list of such elements on disk, and reload them later.
I tried with java classes (ObjectOutputStream, fileOutputStream, objectInputStream, fileInputStream) but I have an error in the retrieving step : the statement

```
val n2 = ois.readObject().asInstanceOf[List[Rdv]]
```

always get an error(classNotFound:Rdv), although the correct path is given in the imports place.

Do you know a workaround to save such an object?
Please provide a little piece of code!

thanks

olivier

ps: I have the same error while using the Marshall class, such as in this code:

```
object Application extends Controller {

def index = Action {

//implicit val Rdv2Writes = Json.writes[rdv2]

def rdvTordv2(rdv: Rdv): rdv2 = new rdv2(
  rdv.nom,
  rdv.prénom,
  rdv.dateRDV,
  rdv.heureRDVString,
  rdv.telPortable,
  rdv.telBureau,
  rdv.telPrivé,
  rdv.siteRDV,
  rdv.typeRDV,
  rdv.libelléRDV,
  rdv.orderId,
  rdv.statut)




val n = variables.manager.liste_locale
val out = new FileOutputStream("out")
out.write(Marshal.dump(n))
out.close

val in = new FileInputStream("out")
val bytes = Stream.continually(in.read).takeWhile(-1 !=).map(_.toByte).toArray
val bar: List[Rdv] = Marshal.load[List[Rdv]](bytes)        <--------------

val n3 = bar.map(rdv =>
  rdvTordv2(rdv))
println("n3:" + n3.size)




Ok(views.html.Application.olivier2(n3))

}

},
```

in the line with the arrow.
It seems that the conversion to the type List[Rdv] encounters problems, but why? Is it a play! linked problem?

---

ok, there's a problem with play:
I created a new scala project with this code:

```
object Test1 extends App {

//pour des fins de test
case class Person(name:String,age:Int)
val liste_locale=List(new Person("paul",18))

val n = liste_locale
val out = new FileOutputStream("out")
out.write(Marshal.dump(n))
out.close

val in = new FileInputStream("out")
val bytes = Stream.continually(in.read).takeWhile(-1 !=).map(_.toByte).toArray
val bar: List[Person] = Marshal.load[List[Person]](bytes)
println(s"bar:size=${bar.size}")
}
```

and the display is good ("bar:size=1").

then, I modified my previous code in the play project, in the controller class, such as this:

```
object Application extends Controller {

def index = Action {

//pour des fins de test
case class Person(name:String,age:Int)
val liste_locale=List(new Person("paul",18))

val n = liste_locale
val out = new FileOutputStream("out")
out.write(Marshal.dump(n))
out.close

val in = new FileInputStream("out")
val bytes = Stream.continually(in.read).takeWhile(-1 !=).map(_.toByte).toArray
val bar: List[Person] = Marshal.load[List[Person]](bytes)
println(s"bar:size=${bar.size}")


Ok(views.html.Application.olivier2(Nil))

}

}
```

and I have an error saying:

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[ClassNotFoundException: controllers.Application$$anonfun$index$1$Person$3]]
```

is there anyone having the answer?

edit: I thought the error could come from sbt, so I modified build.scala such as this:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import play.Project._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

val appName = "sms_play_2"
val appVersion = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

val appDependencies = Seq(
// Add your project dependencies here,
jdbc,
anorm,
"com.typesafe.slick" % "slick_2.10" % "2.0.0",
"com.github.nscala-time" %% "nscala-time" % "0.6.0",
"org.xerial" % "sqlite-jdbc" % "3.7.2",
"org.quartz-scheduler" % "quartz" % "2.2.1",
"com.esotericsoftware.kryo" % "kryo" % "2.22",
"io.argonaut" %% "argonaut" % "6.0.2")

val mySettings = Seq(
(javaOptions in run) ++= Seq("-Dconfig.file=conf/dev.conf"))

val playCommonSettings = Seq(

Keys.fork := true)

val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(

  Keys.fork in run := true,
resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots")).settings(mySettings: _*)
.settings(playCommonSettings: _*)

}
```

but without success, the error is still there (Class Person not found)

can you help me?

Comment: You can serialize to some parsable non binary format like JSON which is usually a better option (not always).

Comment: I don't believe "the correct path is given". The path must include the class you're deserializing.

Comment: @som-snytt : I have, in the version with Marshall the import of metier.Objets.Rdv!!!help!

Comment: I meant "runtime class path", not the fully-qualified name. HTH.

Comment: ok, but how can I change this in eclipse for play! ?I searched quickly but found nothing thzt could help

Answer (score 0):

[Scala Pickling](https://github.com/scala/pickling) has reasonable momentum and the approach has many advantages (lots of the heavy lifting is done at compile time).  There is a plugable serialization mechanism and formats like json are supported.